# How does the cell-wall ultrastructure of gram negative bacteria justify it being unable to Sporulate?

Tags: evolution, cell-biology, microbiology, bacteriology, cell-division

The following is a quote from my Microbiology Lecture PPT: "*Some gram positive bacteria but NEVER gram negative ones produce spores under harsh conditions*".

It got me wondering why gram negative bacteria is "NEVER" involved in sporulation? At this level of which the argument has been presented, I deduce that the distinction should be in the cell-wall ultrastructure differences (gram positive vs gram negative). I do understand the ultra-structural differences between gram positive and gram negative bacteria but I cannot relate it to Sporulation, that is, **how does the cell-wall ultrastructure of gram negative bacteria justify it being unable to Sporulate?**

Before you mention it, yes I did approach my professor about it, and she, too, got interested to know about this and we are both on a quest to find an answer for such a seemingly interesting question.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "justify"?

Comment: Provides a scientifically plausible reasoning for why gram negative bacteria cannot sporulate with the reasoning being attributed to the cell wall ultra structural differences (vs. gram positive bacteria). Hope this helps. @BryanKrause

Comment: Endospore formation is probably unique to a single phylum (Firmicutes) and requires something like 80 different genes. Non-Firmicutes spore-formers (just a handful of Actinobacteria that I'm aware of) use a substantially different mechanism resulting in different spore structures lacking certain components essential to endospore formation. Seems like a bit of a stretch to assume the cell wall structure is the primary limitation.